# Complex Configuration Class asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, user-controls, html

I have a complex class for configuration, which holds all the configuration data, and I'm reading this class in a separate class that exists in the business class library. In my web project, I am reading this in a pagebase class - which all my aspx pages inherit. I have the class as a property in pagebase, and I can access it in my aspx pages fine. But how do I access this in the usercontrols? Is there a global way to keep this class in memory (I can't have it as static, because its different per user) and I'd rather not use sessions. I was thinking there is a way to have it as part of a global properties somewhere, so I can always use it anywhere in the web project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its on all your pages you can just cast the page object to your base page and access the property.

inside a usercontrol.

```
((MyBasePage)this.Page).MyConfigObject
```

Comment: You could also put it in the application object which is like session but global.  Then the base page property simply accesses it

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in [HttpContext.Current.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) dictionary around page creation time. It will be avaialbe during lifetime of that request.

Note: Tey to find other ways to achieve whatever you want to achieve without global/per-request state...

Comment: I agree with your note - what are my other options? Basically I have a configuration class for my entire application. I just want a clean way to be able to use this everywhere.